# Why loadCount() introduced and its actual usage into laravel

Tags: laravel

> I already read doc here :
>   https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/25997

What i want to know is by using `withCount()` we were just load count of records  instead of getting all relations data.

**So by using `loadCount()` what we can do ?**

Please explain in short in simple words. 
Thanks

Comment: I think the implementation is weird. It pretty much reloads all models with all attributes and adds the given relation count. But the side effect of reloading all models is questionable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

loadCount Eloquent Collection Method introduced by the release of Laravel 5.7.10. According to the [laravel-news](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-7-10).

**loadCount** is the ability to load relationship counts on an Eloquent collection. Before this feature, you could only load relationships, but now you can call loadCount() to get counts for all relations.

The pull request illustrates how you could use loadCount() with the following **example**:

```
$events = Event::latest()->with('eventable')->paginate();

$groups = $events->map(function ($event) {
    return $event->eventable;
})->groupBy(function ($eventable) {
    return get_class($eventable);
});

$groups[Post::class]->loadCount('comments');
$groups[Comment::class]->loadCount('hearts');

return new EventIndexResponse($events);
```